# Ways to restrict recursive application launch in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, process

I am running an **interactive application (binary) as a default login shell** for all users.
This application has **capability to open new bash shell** (`fork+exec` based on user input) to provide access to some Linux commands.

On this new shell, **users should not be allowed to run another instance of the same application**, to do this I am passing an **env (EXTRA_SHELL=true)** variable while launching the bash shell and in the application `if getenv("EXTRA_SHELL") == true: exit:` then I am exiting.

But this is **not a safest way** to do this because **unsetting or overwriting the env** will allow users to create new instance of the application.

How to add this restriction in a safe way?
[Note: I thought of somehow using the `ps --forest` for the same, but no idea how to use it]

Answer (score 1):

> How to add this restriction **in a safe way**?

Create a completely separate chroot that just does not have that application. For example when creating that new bash shell, chroot into a prepared environment. You may want to use `proot` and user namespaces, so that you don't need root.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but I have resource constraints to create chroot for each user, and new users can also be created using this application. So what I meant by safe way is that, the logged in user should not be able to bypass the mechanism I will be using to find recursive application launch. Can you suggest such a mechanism?

Comment: ? I do not understand. I suggested, use `proot` with a prepared chroot.